# How to put an exported/clean directory BACK under SVN control?

Tags: svn, version-control

Say I exported a versioned directory, thus making a clean copy of it without all the .svn folders. Now I want to put this version back to version control.

Doing "checkout" on the root directory to link it back to the SVN repository does not work, it seems.

I know this is a situation that should not really occur but I am rather interested by a solution for understanding purposes.

Answer (score 3):

I'll assume you've made changes to your exported code. Otherwise, there isn't any real problem since all your code is in the repository, thus your exported folder is disposable.

If you haven't renamed or removed anything, you can simply checkout a fresh working copy (i.e., a copy without unsaved local changes) and drop your exported folder on top. Overwrite existing files when prompted and you're almost done. Review changes and commit.

If there are deletions and the like, you can use a file compare utility to copy your exported files to the working copy and remove the ones that no longer exists, but you'll need further tweaking.

Comment: That would work in a practical context, however in my case I would like to do this "in place", that is, put the *original* directory under SVN control without having to delete a single file from it.

Comment: Then drop your working copy on top of your export and answer **No** when prompted to overwrite. *(Do you edit exports in a regular basis?)*

Comment: You could even keep track of deletions by removing the original files after doing the checkout, and then copying the exported tree over.

Comment: @Zak - Cool tip. The newer *single .svn directory* working copy format allows to do it nicely.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `svn import` to get the code back under version control.

I assume there are changes in your source tree that you're trying to preserve -- otherwise, there is no reason to try and re-add version control meta data back to the source, you'd just do a fresh `svn checkout`.

Therefore, once you do `svn import` to get the source back under version control, then you can use `svn merge` to diff the source tree to another branch.  Then, commit the changes and you have effectively gotten the changes back under version control.

Comment: This involves making changes to the repository. I just want to put a directory under SVN control, not commit its changes - at least at first.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a new checkout of exact revision you had at the moment of the export (you have to know the revision number!). Then drop everything except .svn folders (use bash/etc to do it), then copy your directory on top of it.